# Blazor app slow loading due to multiple json downloading and parsing

Tags: json, blazor, blazor-server-side

I made a Blazor app that downloads and parses two json files. My app takes ages to load. Especially after adding the second json file download, things got slow (stuck at Loading... for a long time).

Even when I click any button with onclick event; one of them for example that shows a popup in a form of BlazoredModel; it so appears that the entire page starts loading again from scratch before loading the popup model. Even a simple onlick event with a static method takes forever to happen.

This is the code:

```
@if (players is null)
{
    <td>
        <p>Loading...</p>
    </td>
}
else
{
    @foreach(var player in players)
    {
        if (player.Steam == null)
            continue;

        @Task.Run( async() => await PlayerCivs(player.Steam, 'w')).Result //this line downloads/parses 1st json
        @Task.Run( async() => await GetMatchesHistory(player.Steam)).Result //this line downloads/parses 2st json
        etc..

@code {
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
 
    private async Task showPOP()
    {
        ControlID.IDplayer = 34;
        modal.Show<Edit>("Edit Player");
    }

    public async Task<decimal> PlayerCivs(string steamid, char f)
    {
        var dnl = await DownloadStringAsync(steamid, @"https://aoe2.net/api/player/ratinghistory?game=aoe2de&leaderboard_id=3&steam_id=",1);

        var playerRank = PlayerRank.FromJson(dnl);

        numWINS = playerRank[0].NumWins;
        numLOSS = playerRank[0].NumLosses;
        numStreak = (int)playerRank[0].Streak;
        numRate = (int)playerRank[0].Rating;
        Perc = Math.Round(((decimal)playerRank[0].NumWins / ((decimal)playerRank[0].NumLosses + (decimal)playerRank[0].NumWins)) * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
        return Math.Round(((decimal)playerRank[0].NumWins / ((decimal)playerRank[0].NumLosses + (decimal)playerRank[0].NumWins)) * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    public async Task<int> GetMatchesHistory(string steamid)
    {
        string dnl = "";
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => {dnl = DownloadStringAsync(steamid, @"https://aoe2.net/api/player/matches?game=aoe2de&steam_id=", 500).Result; });
        thread.Start();

        while (dnl == "")
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
        }

        //var dnl = await DownloadStringAsync(steamid, @"https://aoe2.net/api/player/matches?game=aoe2de&steam_id=",500);
        var matchesHistory = MatchesHistory.FromJson(dnl);
        //3 best civs
        //most played map

       List<decimal> mapnums = new List<decimal>();
       List<decimal> allmapnums = new List<decimal>();

       if (matchesHistory == null)
            return 0;

       foreach (var item in matchesHistory)
       {
            foreach (var pl in item.Players)
            {
                foreach(var j in item.Players)
                {
                    if (pl.SteamId == steamid)
                        allmapnums.Add((decimal)j.Civ);

                    if(pl.SteamId == steamid && pl.Won == true)
                    {
                        mapnums.Add((decimal)j.Civ);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var first = mapnums.GroupBy(i => i)
                           .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
                           .Select(grp => grp.Key).ElementAt(0);
        var second = mapnums.GroupBy(i => i)
                            .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
                            .Select(grp => grp.Key).ElementAt(1);
        var third = mapnums.GroupBy(i => i)
                           .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
                           .Select(grp => grp.Key).ElementAt(2);

        firstNUM = first;
        secondNUM = second;
        thirdNUM = third;

        //times repeated first => decimal

        percfirst = Math.Round((Repeatedx(first, mapnums) / Repeatedx(first, allmapnums)) * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        percsecond = Math.Round((Repeatedx(second, mapnums) / Repeatedx(second, allmapnums)) * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        percthird = Math.Round((Repeatedx(third, mapnums) / Repeatedx(third, allmapnums)) * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

        return 0;
    }

    async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string id,string iurl,int cnt, int timeOut = 60000)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# console program");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        //var content = client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(iurl + id + @"&count="+cnt)).Result;
        
            return await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri(iurl + id + @"&count=" + cnt));
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        StartTimer();
        
        numROWS = A();
        players = await _db.GetPlayers();
    }

    public void StartTimer()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += CountDownTimer;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    public async void CountDownTimer(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (A() != numROWS)
        {
            players = await _db.GetPlayers();
            numROWS = A();
        }
        else
            return;

        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }
    etc.
}
```

I'm using 11 Nuget packages:

- Blazored.Modal.
- CurrieTechnologies.Razor.Clipboard.
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.
- MySqlConnector.
- Newtonsoft.Json.
- Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.
- System.Data.Entity.Repository.
- System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.
- System.Text.Json.

Why is it so slow rendering? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

I could add more code from `program.cs` or `appsettings.json` or anything you request. I'm stuck with this for 1 months now and it's my first Blazor project.

Thank you very much

Comment: arent you using API's to get the response? why are you downloading them into files?

Comment: after calling an API parse the response into c# data model also you can try to limit the response if your api allows for that.

Comment: also `foreach(var j in item.Players)` this nested i think you need to remove this, it should not be there as both `foreach loop` have the same source

Comment: Do not use `Task.Run()`. Do not use `.Result`.   Do not put loading code in the markup section.

Comment: @WajeehHasan Good catch with the foreach duplicate source. Fixed it but the issue is still there.

Comment: @HenkHolterman If I don't use `Task.Run()` or `.Result` What else should I use? I will try to handle downloading strings in `override OnitializedAsync()` and get back to you see if that helps. Thanks

Comment: @HenkHolterman Handling the download of json strings within `OnitializedAsync()` fixed the problem with onclick event; all the click event take place though the loadding is in progress. 
The main loading issue persists partially as I have to click any button to force the rendering of the table although it's not finished. Which I can not make it happen because players object is null. I want to force the rendering of foreach section though the object is empty. Thanks you!

Comment: it's the same question and same problem of (Slow loading) Your suggestion to move Tasks to `OnitializedAsync()` solved the issue of onclick events doubling the load time if you click them. I feel it's best I explain this in a 30 seconds video https://streamable.com/wdt2di

So you have solved part of the loading problem but the other part is explained in the video. Thank you so much!

Comment: @HenkHolterman I figured out the the second part of slow loading. All I had to do is add `StateHasChanged();` at the end of the manupulation of model objects. I will post an answer to explain further. Please post your answer emphasizing to move all network Tasks to Oninitilized method and never implement them into the html.

Comment: I'm waiting for you to post the answer so I approve it.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Seriously man I can't thank you enough I was stuck on this for a month now and I can't believe something as simple as moving the tasks could help this much. If you don't mind where can I find tips like this in case I get stuck? FYI i'm not a fan of MSDN the formatting of that site is a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found out, Rendering (the razor markup/html code) can be executed quite often.

So the normal practice is to load data in OnInitializedAsync(). Or OnParamersSetAsync() when your data relies on parameters. See [this picture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#lifecycle-events).

Now your core code is

```
await Task.Run(async () => await PlayerCivs(player.Steam, 'w'));
await Task.Run(async () => await GetMatchesHistory(player.Steam));
await Task.Run(async () => await fw());
```

We can improve on that. It uses 3 async lambda methods that don't do anything but do cost a little. Task.Run() will accept any Task, we can make it:

```
await Task.Run(() => PlayerCivs(player.Steam, 'w'));
await Task.Run(() => GetMatchesHistory(player.Steam));
await Task.Run(fw);
```

The 3 methods now run async (with respect to the Blazor framework) but still sequential. I would expect the following to run faster (time = Max(a,b,c) instead of time = Sum(a,b,c) )

```
var t1 = Task.Run(() => PlayerCivs(player.Steam, 'w'));
var t2 = Task.Run(() => GetMatchesHistory(player.Steam));
var t3 = Task.Run(fw);
await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3);
```

Furthermore, Task.Run() is ineffective in Blazor Wasm and doubtful on Blazor Server. Do try:

```
var t1 = () => PlayerCivs(player.Steam, 'w');
var t2 = () => GetMatchesHistory(player.Steam);
var t3 = fw();
await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2,t3);
```

Comment: Thank you for the addition to improve my code! I will use your suggestion and thank you a million for taking time and doing all this I really appreciate it <3

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HenkHolterman I learnt an important lesson in Blazor. "Even if you can do it, it does not mean It works as perfect as you want" - so even if Blazor lets us implement Tasks and methods directly into the html, It's counter-performance especially Tasks that download strings or data from the internet (Apis).

I did move my foreach loop with the Tasks that download json strings to `OnitializedAsync()` and that ladies and gents fixed some bugs where when I click any button the page reloads from scratch for no reason and reduced the rendering time of the browser.

Coming to the second issue which is also related to slow rendering is the fact that I was not calling `StateHasChanged();` whenever I make changes to my model object. It looks like this

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        StartTimer();
        numROWS = A();
        
        //Grabbing mysql data and parsing it to my model object which is "players"
        players = await Task.Run(async () => await _db.GetPlayers());
        //Calling Statehaschanged to asynchronously re-render my model object into html without reloading the entire page.
        StateHasChanged();
        //Here I'm reading the object model and parsing more data into it.
        foreach (var player in players)
        {
            if (player.Steam == null)
                continue;

            await Task.Run(async () => await PlayerCivs(player.Steam, 'w'));
            await Task.Run(async () => await GetMatchesHistory(player.Steam));
            await Task.Run(async () => await fw());
            player.WinRate = PLAYERATE;
            player.Civ1 = await GetCivName(firstNUM);
            player.Civ1alt = civALT;

            player.Civ2 = await GetCivName(secondNUM);
            player.Civ2alt = civALT;

            player.Civ3 = await GetCivName(thirdNUM);
            player.Civ3alt = civALT;
            //Again!! We call statehaschanged to update the table row concerned with the model object item.
            StateHasChanged();
        }


    }
```

By calling StateHasChanged() a few time, I'm updating my html table row by row and even component by component if I want to.

Although this is the answer to my question which I struggled to fix for a month, I'm still obliged to credit @HenkHolterman and mark his reply as the answer because without his tip to move all tasks to the code section is the solution to this problem and helped me figure other things too. So thank you again Henk <3